# EDB Postgres server from local host Apache, Server is up and running The default Apache context is www in the Apache installation

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

I have been trying to get rid of postgresEDB apache HTTP server within my localhost and I am failing to do it. I have tried various options, including:

```
netstat -ano|findstr :8080
```

and

```
taskkill /pid number /F
```

but failed, as everytime I re-start system and type localhost, this pops up.

I've uninstalled EnterpriseDB and PostgreSQL, but still no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

I have the same issue, and stopping **PEM HTTPD** works form me.

1. go to "run" then "services.msc"
2. find a service called "PEM HTTPD", description Apache/2.4.39 (Win32)
3. right-click and select stop or disable the service.

Note: The process that runs on port 8080 was httpd. I used resmon.exe to find out about the process.

[How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I neeeded help with the same issue and the answer didn't work for me. What worked was:

1. go to "run" then "services.msc"
2. find a service called "pgbouncer", the description says it is a "lightweight connection pooler for postgres"
3. right-click and select stop

if you needed the localhost:8080 all the time perhaps you could change the startup type to disabled too. but for a one time use, stopping it works.

I am running windows on bootcamp on a macbook, hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but I thought I'd throw the answer out there in case this is the first page anyone hits (as was the case with me).

On Windows you can kill this task through the Services applet.

1. Go to "Run"
2. Type "services.msc"
3. In the Services app, look for the following lines:

   - EnterpriseDB ApacheHTTPD
   - EnterPriseDB ApachePHP
4. Double click on each service.
5. Change "Startup type:" to "Disabled"
6. Click "Stop"
7. Click "Apply"
8. Repeat for the other service

This will ensure that you won't have to contend with the service popping up every time you restart your PC.

This information is available on the EDBPostgres site as well https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/6.0.2/peminstguide/installation_guide.1.30.html

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Amazing thanks, you saved my day. 

This works fine for me after looking for a permanent solution for days.